# Finding maxima and minima at certain points Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given the following:

```
 toy = pd.DataFrame({
                'price': [100, 103, 107, 105, 99, 96, 98, 103],
                'barrier': [102, 102, 102,102,102,102, 102, 102],
                'date': ['2020-02-28', '2020-03-01', '2020-03-02','2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020- 
                          03-05', '2020-03-06', '2020-03-07']})

toy['date'] = pd.to_datetime(toy['date']) #just make datetime obj
toy['rets'] = np.log(toy['price']/toy['price'].shift(1))
toy['ret_cum'] = toy['rets'].cumsum()
toy['loop'] = [0, 103, 0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 103] #some signal
toy['inten'] = 0.0 #initialize
```

I would like `toy['inten']` to be `max(toy['ret_cum'].iloc[1,4])` when loop is 99 (ie 0.067..) , then `min(toy['ret_cum'].iloc[5,7])` (ie -0.0408) when loop is 103 and so on.

More generally, `np.where(toy['loop'] != 0)` yields (1,4,7)...and i'd like to check the maximum levels reached in the interval 1 to 4, then 5 to 7 etc.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to find min values or max values in the interval? Please include your expected output.

Comment: I did :) "when loop is 99  output shuld be 0.067..then min(toy['ret_cum'].iloc[5,7]) (ie -0.0408) when loop is 103 and so on. Thanks

Comment: its not clear what you want, its better if you include the desired output in the question i.e final values of `intent` column.

Comment: Why is `toy.loc[1,'inten']` zero. What is the logic here?

Comment: toy.loc[1, 'inten']  is the beginning of the series and not enough data to generate a signal. From loc[4, 'inten'] onwards should generate as per above though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this might work.  It alternates between min and max since specific criteria behind that wasn't provided.

```
start = -1
stop = -1
count = 0
for i in toy.index:
    if stop > max(toy.index):
        break
    if toy.loc[i, "loop"] != 0:
        if count == 0:
            start = i
        else:
            stop = i
            if count % 2 == 0:
                toy.loc[i, "inten"] = toy.loc[start:stop, "ret_cum"].min()
            else:
                toy.loc[i, "inten"] = toy.loc[start:stop, "ret_cum"].max()
            start = stop + 1
        count += 1
```

Output -

```
   price  barrier       date      rets   ret_cum  loop     inten
0    100      102 2020-02-28       NaN       NaN     0  0.000000
1    103      102 2020-03-01  0.029559  0.029559   103  0.000000
2    107      102 2020-03-02  0.038100  0.067659     0  0.000000
3    105      102 2020-03-03 -0.018868  0.048790     0  0.000000
4     99      102 2020-03-04 -0.058841 -0.010050    99  0.067659
5     96      102 2020-03-05 -0.030772 -0.040822     0  0.000000
6     98      102 2020-03-06  0.020619 -0.020203     0  0.000000
7    103      102 2020-03-07  0.049762  0.029559   103 -0.040822
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. And if eventually the index becomes datetime object toy['date'] then I can just change from toy.loc[i, 'loop'] to toy['loop'].iloc[i] and so forth.

Comment: For sure.  Pandas has a lot of cool datetime features.  One you might look at is .rolling() for local min/max. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.min.html.  Resampler is another datetime-friendly group: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.max.html